# DatatableEditor vincular habilitar input apenas se estiver selecionado

Tags: ajax, datatable

Estou com uma duvida de como realizar este procedimento, Utilizei o **DatatableEditor** e **Ajax** para realizar este modal.

Preciso que o calendário atrelado ao Treinamento,

> Ex: Palestra -- exibe os calendários para este treinamento.
>
> Os dados do campo "Calendário" vem do Ajax após selecionar o "Treinamento"

mas apenas após eu escolher o treinamento, que ele irá habilitar o campo calendário com o resultado condizente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os dados do campo "calendário" vem do Ajax após selecionar o "treinamento"?

Comment: isso que eu quero fazer.